# Lumen returns always 200 for Controllers

Tags: php, lumen

I am trying to do a small rest api which based on Lumen. Everything is ok for this sample:

**routes/web.php**

```
$router->post('foo/', function () {
    return response('[]', 400)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```

postman receives this response:

[image: 400]

400 - bad request. That's ok. But if I try to do the same with a controller php file:

**routes/web.php**

```
$router->post('accounts/', 'AccountController@register');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/AccountController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class AccountController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function register(Request $request): string {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'failed'], 400);
    }
}
```

[image]

status code is: 200? But why?
Headers came in body response...
Can you advice something to solve this case?

Comment: Try to remove `: string`. Maybe some converting of `Response` object to `string` is performed.

Comment: @u_mulder, thx! It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining function's return type like `string` you tell php to make everything (unless `strict_types` declared) to convert anything to `string`. I presume somewhere in `Response` class there's a `__toString` method which outputs data as you see in your picture. So, just remove return type declaration. Or change it to `Response`. It is `Response` class's responsibility to process data and output it as required, not your controller:

```
public function register(Request $request) 
{
    return response()->json(['message' => 'failed'], 400);
}
```

Comment: Thx! I have changed return type to `JsonResponse`

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I'm facing this same problem, in production, the server always return 200, on status code, even when I explicitly set the response like this topic suggest. There is any apache configuration that could maybe override this code? I'm asking about apache because it works as expected in another server.